# access localize css file through SharePoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

1) how can i access _layout/1033/styles/custom.css file with SharePoint Designer ?

2) if i created a folder named 1033 through SharePoint Design in Style Library. What setting i have to make in master page to pick localized folder.

Comment: I am modified corev4.css at save with in _style/corev4.css If I opened designer I could not see <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/_styles/corev4.css" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/> do you why I can't see this in designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use sharepoint designer then it is best to make a copy of this file and place it in the style library. Create a custom folder and custom CSS and use it in Site. Register your Custom CSS in master page using `CssRegistration`, see below:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="customfolder/custom.css" runat="server"/>
```

**Note: Alternate CSS on Server but comes before corev4.css**

The order in which CSS will load actually:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/customfolder/custom.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css"/>
```

The after  attribute:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name=”customfolder/custom.css” After=”corev4.css” runat=”server”/>
```

**Note: Alternate CSS on Server and comes after corev4.css.**

The order in which CSS will load actually:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/customfolder/custom.css"/>
```

**Update**

Open SharePoint Designer (SPD) and connect to the root level of your site's site collection.

In SPD, open the "Style Library" folder.

Create a new CSS file and name it (e.g. "customstyles.css").

Open your master page file in SPD.

In the `<head>` tag add a link to your custom CSS just above the content place holder named "`PlaceHolderAdditonalPageHead`" as follows:

```
<link href="/Style%20Library/customstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: how can i register localized custom folder and css file created in style library in master page.

Comment: i have updated my response...

Comment: i have created 1033/site.css and 1036/site.css  in style library how i register file in master page so multi language site can use it. any blog or example would be appreciated

Comment: Here you go: http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2007/10/25/sharepoint-branding-part-4-packaging-up-your-masterpiece-into-a-feature/